# Java string split by 0x00

Tags: java, android

How can I do that?

I tried

```
return so.split("\\x00");
```

or

```
return so.split(String.valueOf(0x00));
```

nothing worked (so is my string)

thanks, 
Leslie

Comment: Have you tried `so.split("0x00");` ?

Comment: That would not work, not even close.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill It will if the string is `Hello0x00World!` ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put a zero character into a String, you could simply do

```
so.split("\u0000");
```

You can use this syntax to encode any 16-bit Unicode character.

Comment: +1: Or `so.split("\0");` or `so.split(Character.toString(0));` or `so.split("" + (char) 0);`

Comment: Or `so.split(new String(new byte[1], 0));`